# Serde custom serializer

Tags: rust, serde

I am following a [guide](https://serde.rs/impl-serializer.html) for implementing a serializer with `serde`. It gives a basic implementation of a JSON serializer using Serde. Say that I only want to serialize the unsigned integers `u8`, `u16` and `u32`. Is it possible to somehow specify this constraint and throw errors whenever the user tries to serialize any other type like `string`, `f32` etc. ?

I could probably write

```
fn serialize_string(self, v: string) -> Result<()> {
    return Err(Error::Message("Undefined".to_owned()));
}

fn serialize_f32(self, v: f32) -> Result<()> {
    return Err(Error::Message("Undefined".to_owned()));
}

/* and so forth */
```

But this feels too verbose.

And is it possible to define a protocol for serializing custom types? For example I might have a struct `Point` containing two coordinates `x` and `y`. I want to serialize `Point` in a compressed format as explained here: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/84588, I.e. serialize the first `x` coordinate as any other unsigned integer but add a small prefix to indicate if the `y` coordinate is even or odd. One can then derive `y` from `x` by using the prefix (conditional).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not really any way around implementing all of the unused cases. If you find it is causing too much clutter, you could try making a macro for the unused functions or add a wrapper trait with default implementations of each function.

As for serializing custom types, there are a couple approaches, but I am not sure if there is an official recommended approach.

An easy way to do this though is to leverage `Serializer::serialize_newtype_struct` and `Deserializer::deserialize_newtype_struct`. These functions are normally used for cases where you have a tuple struct with a single value. However, they give the option for your serializer to switch to a new serializer type for the inner value based on the name without modifying any of the serializer's associated types. So that means you can define a name that is highly unlikely to be used anywhere outside your serializer, and switch to a different serializer/deserializer strategy if it ever comes up.

```rust
/// New type name name used to convey to serializer/deserializer that our special point type
/// is being used. String intentionally contains null character to make it highly unlikely
/// that another implementation would use the same type name.
const POINT_INTERNAL_NAME: &'static str = "foo::Point\x08";
```

Then you define your special type announce it is actually a new type with this internal name.

```rust
/// The type we want to implement a custom serialization approach for
pub struct Point {
    pub x: f32,
    pub y: f32,
}

impl Serialize for Point {
    fn serialize<S: Serializer>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        struct PointProxy {
            x: f32,
            y: f32,
        }

        /// This is exactly the same as what would have been generated if we used 
        /// `#[derive(Serialize)]` on [Point]. We implement this manually in this case to
        /// ensure that the implementation stays stable even if a change is made to
        /// `serde_derive`.
        impl Serialize for PointProxy {
            fn serialize<S: Serializer>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
                let mut struct_serializer = serializer.serialize_struct("Point", 2)?;
                struct_serializer.serialize_field("x", &self.x)?;
                struct_serializer.serialize_field("y", &self.y)?;
                struct_serializer.end()
            }
        }

        let proxy_value = Point {
            x: self.x,
            y: self.y,
        };

        serializer.serialize_newtype_struct(POINT_INTERNAL_NAME, &proxy_value)
    }
}
```

Finally, the serializer picks which approach it uses when serializing.

```rust
impl Serializer for FooSerializer {
    fn serialize_newtype_struct<T: Serialize + ?Sized>(
        self,
        name: &'static str,
        value: &T
    ) -> Result<Self::Ok, Self::Error> {
        if name == POINT_INTERNAL_NAME {
            return value.serialize(FooSpecialSerializer::new(self));
        }

        // Handle all other cases normally
        value.serialize(self)
    }

    /* etc. */
}
```

Then you implement a special serializer custom made for the specific type.

```rust
struct FooPointSerializer<W> {
    out: W,
    x: Option<f32>,
    y: Option<f32>,
}

impl<W: Write> Serializer for FooPointSerializer<W> {
    type SerializeStruct = Self;

    fn serialize_struct(
        self,
        name: &'static str,
        len: usize
    ) -> Result<Self::SerializeStruct, Self::Error> {
        // Only our Point implementation should be using this serializer
        assert_eq!(name, "Point");
        assert_eq!(len, 2);

        Ok(self)
    }

    /* etc. */
}

impl<W: Write> SerializeStruct  for FooPointSerializer<W> {
    type Ok = ();
    type Error = <FooSerializer as Serializer>::Error;

    // Required methods
    fn serialize_field<T: Serialize + ?Sized>(
        &mut self,
        key: &'static str,
        value: &T
    ) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        // How you convert the value to your desired type is up to you. In this case, assume
        // there is a serializer that fills in value upon a call to serialize_f32 and errors
        // in all other cases.
        let mut value: f32 = 0.0;
        value.serialize(ExpectSerializeF32(&mut value))?;

        // Verify assumptions about fields
        match key {
            "x" => {
                assert!(x.is_none(), "Expected 'x' to be first field in Point");
                self.x = Some(value);
            },
            "y" => {
                assert!(x.is_some() && y.is_none(), "Expected 'y' to be second field in Point");
                self.y = Some(value);
            },
            _ => panic!("Unexpected field {:?} while serializing point", key),
        }

        Ok(())
    }


    fn end(mut self) -> Result<Self::Ok, Self::Error> {
        let (Some(x), Some(y)) = (self.x, self.y) else {
             panic!("Point did not serialize expected number of fields");
        }

        // Implement custom serialization for this type
        self.out.write_all(&[POINT_TYPE_TAG])?;
        self.out.write_all(&x.to_be_bytes())?;
        self.out.write_all(&y.to_be_bytes())?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that the vast majority of serializers put no significance on the names of new type structs so it is a fairly safe assumption that if anyone uses your custom `Point` type in another serializer (such as `serde_json`), it will serialize the same way as `#[derive(Serialize)]` would.